# React, dynamic dropdown downshift

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

Im fairly new to React and i'm trying to create a dropdown where users can add values to the dropdown. Something like this [What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtA5o.png)

This is what i got now, but the add button dosent work at all
[My dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/919VQ.png)
I had another input field where i could pass the value to the dropdown, but when i tried to implement the logic to the downshift dropdown nothing happened. No error, no value!

Here is my code:

```
function BasicAutocomplete({ items, onChange }) {
  return (
    <Downshift
      onChange={onChange}
      render={({
        getInputProps,
        getItemProps,
        isOpen,
        inputValue,
        selectedItem,
        highlightedIndex,
        handleSubmit
      }) => (
          <div>
            <Input {...getInputProps({ placeholder: 'Markedsaktivitet'}) } ref="input"  />
            {isOpen ? (
              <div style={{ border: '1px solid #ccc' }}>
                {items
                  .filter(
                  i =>
                    !inputValue ||
                    i.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()),
                )
                  .map((item, index) => (
                    <div
                      {...getItemProps({ item }) }
                      key={item}
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                          highlightedIndex === index ? 'gray' : 'white',
                        fontWeight: selectedItem === item ? 'bold' : 'normal',
                      }}
                    >
                      { item }
                    </div>
                  ))}
                <Button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}><i className="fa fa-plus" /> Add option</Button>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        )}
    />
  )
}

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputField: 'no value',
      items: ['apple', 'orange', 'carrot']
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    const newItem = this.refs.input.value
    this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(newItem) })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <BasicAutocomplete
          items={this.state.items}
          onChange={selectedItem => console.log(selectedItem)}
          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for the replays!

Comment: you are passing a prop named onChange to BasicAutoComplete component , this prop contains a method which takes an argument But in your Downshift component you are setting that props to onChange property of Downshift but there you are not specifying any parameters, Please check if that is the problem

Comment: It seems like the handleSubmit cant reach the Input in the BasicAutocomplete function

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap dropdown menu its good and nice looking 
check out 
and maybe you find something

[Check here there is diffrent model](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/)